# Why are lines with depth of 1 added to array[1]

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, nested

I'm using the following functions to convert a tabbed list to array, but tabs with depth of 1 are added to array[1];

The tab list:

```
    $test = "Test
        Sub Item Test 1 (Test)
        Sub Item Test 2 (Test)
                Sub Sub Item Test 1 (Sub Item Test 2)
            Sub Sub Sub Item Test 1 (Sub Item Test 2)
    Test 2
        Sub Item Test 1 (Test 2)
    Test 3
        Sub Item Test 1 (Test 3)
    Test 4
        Sub Item Test 1 (Test 4)
    Test 5
        Sub Item Test 1 (Test 5)";
```

The functions:

```
    function convert( $list, $indent = "\t" ) {

        $main          = array();

        foreach ( explode( PHP_EOL, $list ) as $line ) {
            $depth = substr_count( $line, $indent );
            $line  = trim( $line );
            if ( $line == '' ) {
                continue;
            }

            $a   = &buildArray( $main, $depth, 0, $line );
            $a[$i++] = $line;
        }

        return $main;

    }

    function &buildArray( &$array, $depth, $current = 0, $line = null ) {

        if ( $depth == $current ) {
            return $array;
        } else {
            foreach ( $array as &$value ) {
                if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
                    return buildArray( $value, $depth, ++ $current );
                }
            }

            $tmp  = array();
            $array[] = &$tmp;

            return buildArray( $tmp, $depth, ++ $current );
        }
    }
```

Here is the result after running "convert($test)"

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Test
        [1] => Array
            (
                [1] => Sub Item Test 1 (Test)
                [2] => Sub Item Test 2 (Test)
                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [3] => Sub Sub Item Test 1 (Sub Item Test 2)
                            )

                        [4] => Sub Sub Sub Item Test 1 (Sub Item Test 2)
                    )

                [6] => Sub Item Test 1 (Test 2)
                [8] => Sub Item Test 1 (Test 3)
                [10] => Sub Item Test 1 (Test 4)
                [12] => Sub Item Test 1 (Test 5)
            )

        [5] => Test 2
        [7] => Test 3
        [9] => Test 4
        [11] => Test 5
    )
```

So why do I get array[1][6] instead of array[6], and so on for all the lines after array[5]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be easier if you re-design how you will store the data. My suggestion is that for every level create an array with key for the label and another key for the sublevels.

```
$test = "Test 1\n
\tSub Item Test 1
\t\tSub Sub Item Test 1
\t\tSub Sub Item Test 2
\tSub Item Test 2
\tSub Item Test 3
\tSub Item Test 4
Test 2\n
\tSub Item Test 1
\tSub Item Test 2
\tSub Item Test 3
\tSub Item Test 4
\t\tSub Sub Item Test 1
\t\tSub Sub Item Test 2";
```

Then it should look something like this after:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        ['label']    => Test 1
        ['children'] => array(
            [0] => Array (
                ['label']    => Sub Item Test 1 (Test 1)
                ['children'] => array()
            )
            [1] => Array (
                ['label']    => Sub Item Test 2 (Test 1)
                ['children'] => array(
                    [0] => Array (
                        ['label']    => Sub Sub Item Test 1 (Sub Item Test 2)
                        ['children'] => array()
                    )
                    [1] => Array (
                        ['label']    => Sub Sub Item Test 2 (Sub Item Test 2)
                        ['children'] => array()
                    )
                )
            )
            [2] => Array (
                ['label']    => Sub Item Test 3 (Test 1)
                ['children'] => array()
            )
        )
    [1] => Array (
        ['label']    => Test 2
        ['children'] => array(
            [0] => Array (
                ['label']    => Sub Item Test 1 (Test 2)
                ['children'] => array()
            )
            [1] => Array (
                ['label']    => Sub Item Test 2 (Test 2)
                ['children'] => array()
            )
            [2] => Array (
                ['label']    => Sub Item Test 3 (Test 2)
                ['children'] => array()
            )
            [3] => Array (
                ['label']    => Sub Item Test 4 (Test 2)
                ['children'] => array(
                    [0] => Array (
                        ['label']    => Sub Sub Item Test 4 (Sub Item Test 4)
                        ['children'] => array()
                    )
                    [1] => Array (
                        ['label']    => Sub Sub Item Test 4 (Sub Item Test 4)
                        ['children'] => array()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```